# react native - AWS + React native sign up with image

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native

I try to use the `Amazon Cognito` for login function. There are some really useful posts guide me to do it. However, I am still wondering how can I upload an avatar for the user.

If you know the way, please let me know.

Here are those useful links I found while researching.

[amplify-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js)

[FB Login w/ React Native + AWS Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384168/fb-login-w-react-native-aws-cognito)

[AWS amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication)

Thank you in advance!